# Displaying of flash content in marker popup

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, leaflet

I try to add swf object in popup by means of Leaflet:

```
var swfContent = '<object><embed src="StrobeMediaPlayback.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" ... 
marker.bindPopup(swfContent);
```

But empty popup shows up when click on marker..
Is there any possibility to display swf content in popup with Leaflet? (with the help of Openlayers no problem)

Thanks in advance

Comment: It emerged that the problem there is in firefox - in chrome swf content displays normally..

Comment: [Example](http://psha.org.ru/leaflet/llytb.html)